# How to insert a polars.lit("some_string") at a specific index?

Tags: python-polars

In `polars`

where `dt` is a `dataFrame`

```py
dt.with_columns(
    new_column = pl.lit('some_text')
)
```

Will add a new column named `new_column` of `some_text`

And

```py
dt.insert_at_idx(index:int, series:series)
```

Will insert a `series` at a given index

But is there a way to combine the two tasks i.e. add a `pl.lit()` at a specific index.

I tried

```py
dt.insert_at_idx(index:int, pl.lit("some_text"))
```

but that did not work.

Does anyone know how to `pl.lit()` at a specified index?

Comment: Can you show an actual example with input / output?

Comment: @jqurious I am working 113 million rows (yes, that's 113 million). I could make a dummy table but how would that be any better than what is already in the post? The post describes a "problem" and gives you all you need to recreate it and solve it, if such a solution exists. It is a problem, insofar as a lack of easy discovery is a problem.

Comment: The issue was `pl.insert_at_idx` doesn't exist so it was unclear if you were talking about row index or column index. The next question I had was if it's column index - what if the index is too large, should empty columns be added to fill? But then I realized `DataFrame.insert_at_idx` was the method you were referring to, and that has an index length limit.

Comment: @jqurious [.insert_at_idx](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/dataframe/api/polars.DataFrame.insert_at_idx.html)

Comment: Yes, thank you. But the name of that method is `pl.DataFrame.insert_at_idx` but your question refers to `pl.insert_at_idx` instead.`AttributeError: module 'polars' has no attribute 'insert_at_idx'`.

Comment: @jqurious, Ah, that was an error on my part! Apologies!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do it by first creating a list of the existing columns, then add the new column as an expression to that list using `.insert`, and finally use `select` to get the columns in that order.

#### One time method

```
df = pl.DataFrame(data={'a':[1,2,3], 'b':[2,3,4], 'c':[3,4,5]})
cols=df.columns
cols.insert(2, pl.lit('some_text').alias("newcol"))
df=df.select(cols)
df
shape: (3, 4)
┌─────┬─────┬───────────┬─────┐
│ a   ┆ b   ┆ newcol    ┆ c   │
│ --- ┆ --- ┆ ---       ┆ --- │
│ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ str       ┆ i64 │
╞═════╪═════╪═══════════╪═════╡
│ 1   ┆ 2   ┆ some_text ┆ 3   │
│ 2   ┆ 3   ┆ some_text ┆ 4   │
│ 3   ┆ 4   ┆ some_text ┆ 5   │
└─────┴─────┴───────────┴─────┘
```

I think the methods that modify the df in place might become deprecated at some point so it may be best to not use them or at least not count on them. I'm not even sure if there are others. You could shortcut the above with a custom function like:

#### Functional method

```
def with_at_idx(df, index, *args, **kwargs):
    if len(args)+len(kwargs)>1:
        raise ValueError("Only one new column allowed")
    # You could, of course, take out this error and the for 
    # loops will continue to work but then you need to deal 
    # with precedent between args and kwargs
    cols=df.columns
    for arg in args:
        cols.insert(index, arg)
    for colname, arg in kwargs.items():
        cols.insert(index, arg.alias(colname))
    return df.select(cols)
pl.DataFrame.with_at_idx=with_at_idx
```

Then you can do:

```
df.with_at_idx(2, new_column=pl.lit(5))
shape: (3, 4)
┌─────┬─────┬────────────┬─────┐
│ a   ┆ b   ┆ new_column ┆ c   │
│ --- ┆ --- ┆ ---        ┆ --- │
│ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ i32        ┆ i64 │
╞═════╪═════╪════════════╪═════╡
│ 1   ┆ 2   ┆ 5          ┆ 3   │
│ 2   ┆ 3   ┆ 5          ┆ 4   │
│ 3   ┆ 4   ┆ 5          ┆ 5   │
└─────┴─────┴────────────┴─────┘
```

OR

```
df.with_at_idx(1, pl.lit("some_text").alias("newcol"))
shape: (3, 4)
┌─────┬───────────┬─────┬─────┐
│ a   ┆ newcol    ┆ b   ┆ c   │
│ --- ┆ ---       ┆ --- ┆ --- │
│ i64 ┆ str       ┆ i64 ┆ i64 │
╞═════╪═══════════╪═════╪═════╡
│ 1   ┆ some_text ┆ 2   ┆ 3   │
│ 2   ┆ some_text ┆ 3   ┆ 4   │
│ 3   ┆ some_text ┆ 4   ┆ 5   │
└─────┴───────────┴─────┴─────┘
```

This does NOT modify the df in place so you'd need to do

`df=df.with_at_idx(...)` to modify the underlying df.